# Django filter on queryset intersection?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, set, intersection

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...

class ItemSet(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name="itemsets")
```

I have a list of ItemSets. I want to find all Item objects where the Item object is in the "items" M2M field on at least one of the ItemSet objects.

How can I do this?

P.S. Here is what I have tried, but to no avail:

```
itemset_list = [itemset1, itemset2, itemset3]    
items = Item.objects.filter(itemsets__in=itemset_list)
```

Comment: Did it error? What happened when you tried that? Also, from where are you getting the list of itemsets? Did you query for them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need your list of itemsets and you didn't get them from a query, try this:

```
itemset_list = [itemset1, itemset2, itemset3]
itemset_list_ids = [itemset.id for itemset in itemset_list]
itemset_queryset = ItemSet.objects.filter(id__in=itemset_list_ids)
items = Item.objects.filter(itemsets__in=itemset_queryset)
```

If you can get your itemset list by querying, that shortens it a little bit:

```
itemset_queryset = ItemSet.objects.filter(SOME FILTER HERE)
items = Item.objects.filter(itemsets__in=itemset_queryset)
```

Comment: In your second example, does Django make one or two queries to get the final `items` QuerySet?

Comment: @Cole it depends on what you do with the "items" variable. If you ask for some fields of "Item" model, Django will make only 1 query. But if you ask for any data external of the "Item" model (for example any data from "ItemSet" model) Django will make 1 query for the "Item" model and many queries for each "ItemSet" (or any other external model). To avoid it, you should include those models in a .select_related() or prefetch_related() queryset methods, depending on the relation between those models and "Item" model.